# Does grunt-recess accept globbing? how I specify files?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm configuring the recess task in gruntfile.js using grunt-recess but I can't get it to work. what I'm doing wrong?

the concerned part in the gruntfile is:

```
recess:{
      dev:{
        options:{
          compile:true
        },
        files:[{
                expand:true,
                cwd:'./',
                src:['<%= yeoman.less %>/**/*.less'],
                dest:['<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/'],
                ext:'.css'
            }]



      }
    }
```

but grunts warns this:

```
 Running "recess:dev" (recess) task
 Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings Use --force to continue.

 Aborted due to warnings.
```

if I change the files object like proposed by @sindresorhus:

```
files:{
          'css/main.css':['less/main.less']
        }
```

I get this:

```
Running "recess:dev" (recess) task

GENERAL USE: $ recess [path] [options]

OPTIONS:
  --compile
  --compress
  --config
  --format
  --includePath
  --noIDs
  --noJSPrefix
  --noOverqualifying
  --noSummary
  --noUnderscores
  --noUniversalSelectors
  --prefixWhitespace
  --strictPropertyOrder
  --stripColors
  --watch
  --zeroUnits
  --inlineImages

EXAMPLE:

  $ recess ./bootstrap.css --noIDs false

GENERAL HELP: http://git.io/recess
```

I'm using node@v0.10.10, npm@1.3.1, grunt@0.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `dest` needs to be a string (either a file name or a folder name) but in your example it is an array. I believe this should work:

```
    files:[{
            expand:true,
            cwd:'./',
            src:['<%= yeoman.less %>/**/*.less'],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css/', // lose the brackets
            ext:'.css'
        }]
  }
```